# How can I limit the amount of strings printed on a single line

Tags: java, string

I want to be able to enter a string `s` and an integer `n`, then print the string `s` `n` times. I have done this, but I want there to be only 2 strings per line.
Here is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter string: ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
        System.out.println(s);

    }

    if(n<0){
        System.out.println("error: number must be positive");
    }

}
```

Let's say the string was `java` and the number was `6`. I need it to output:

```
java java
java java
java java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a simple counter that counts to two inside your for loop. After it reaches two. Add a return character.

```
int count = 0;
for(int j=0; j<n; j++){
   System.out.print(s);
   count++;
   if (count == 2) {
      System.out.print("\n");
      count = 0;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the modulo operator (%) to check if your loop index is evenly divisible by 2.

```
    public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter string: ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    for(int j=1; j<n+1; j++){
        System.out.print(s);
        if (j%2==0)
            System.out.println("\n");
        else
            System.out.print(" ");
    }

    if(n<0){
        System.out.println("error: number must be positive");
    }

    }
```

**EDIT** I changed the output to use `print()` instead of `println()` and added an empty space so the output is formatted as the example in your question.  Also changed the for loop index to be one based so the mod works correctly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter string: ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    for(int j=0; j<n; j++){

    // modified
     if(j%2==0 && j!=0){
        System.out.println("\n");
        }
     System.out.print(s);  // Should this not be print and not println 
         System.out.print(" ");

    // end of modification

    }

    if(n<0){
        System.out.println("error: number must be positive");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int j=0; j<n/2; j++){
        System.out.println(s+" "+s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter string: ");
    String s = in.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please enter number: ");
    int n = in.nextInt();

    for(int j=0; j<n/2; j++){
        System.out.print(s + " " + s + "\n");
    }
    if(n%2 == 1){
        System.out.print(s);
    }

    if(n<0){
        System.out.println("error: number must be positive");
    }
}
```